# Dúvida com método str.replace() do Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.7

Tenho o seguinte texto:

> 'caixa 1 é azul, caixa 10 está verde, caixa 100 está vazia'

Quero então substituir 'caixa 1' por 'pacote 2', logo faço:

```
>>> texto = 'caixa 1 é azul, caixa 10 está verde, caixa 100 está vazia'
>>> print(texto.replace('caixa 1', 'pacote 2'))
pacote 2 é azul, pacote 20 está verde, pacote 200 está vazia
>>>
```

Com isso acabo substituindo tudo que contenha `'caixa 1'` no inicio. Como posso contornar esse problema?

Comment: Acrescente uma virgula: `texto.replace('caixa 1,', 'pacote 2,')`

Comment: Acrescente um espaço: `texto.replace('caixa 1 ', 'pacote 2 ')`. Você não pode estar a editar a pergunta a cada vez que recebe uma resposta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
print(texto.replace('caixa 1 ', 'pacote 2 '))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/Replace.py).

Isto resolve se tiver sempre a vírgula depois. Você tem que ter um padrão que garanta que não terá ambiguidade, caso contrário não tem jeito. Não importa como está composto o texto, precisa ter algo fixo que determine o fim do número de forma não ambígua, pode ser vírgula, espaço, ou qualquer coisa, desde que sempre esteja presente. Se puder ter vários caracteres diferentes, aí precisa fazer uma algoritmo mais sofisticado ou usar `RegEx`.

Comment: Desculpe, não soube passar minha dúvida corretamente então editei para ficar melhor; Infelizmente no texto que estou usando não se tem vírgulas ou qualquer outro caractere que eu possa usar como limitador.

Answer (score 5):

> str.replace(old, new[, max])
>
> - old -- substring a ser modificada
> - new -- a nova substring
> - max -- número de vezes que será substituída

no seu caso

```
print(texto.replace('caixa1','pacote 2', 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta de Maniero, segue uma solução utilizando expressão regular.

```
>>> import re
>>> texto = 'caixa 1 é azul, caixa 10 está verde, caixa 100 está vazia'
>>> re.sub(r'\caixa 1\b', 'pacote 2', texto)
>>> 'pacote é azul, caixa 10 está verde, caixa 100 está vazia'
```